# Forms, Post and submit buttons

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I feel a little silly asking this but I wanted everyones opinion on it.

I want to submit a page, target itself, on the press of a button but carrying one piece of data with it.

Example:

Edit | Delete

On the click on edit, I want the page to reload with `$_POST['example'] === "edit"` or something. I don't want to use `$_GET` and I don't want to use the ugly submit button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably go ahead and use submit buttons, but use CSS to change how they look.
For example:

```
<input class="aslink" type="submit" />

.aslink {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't want to use Javascript for the people who don't support it.

I'll give this a try. Thanks everyone else!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ajax to submit a POST request or style a submit button to look like a link (or whatever else you'd like).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the button tag:

```
<button type="submit">put some html</button>
```

You can put html tags or images in to it and style it to your hearts content.

Answer (score 0):

Create form carrying the data you want to send and send it using JavaScript when you click a link if you want to avoid submit buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You may submit your form via link.

```
<a href='#' onclick='document.myform.submit()'> Edit </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `<input class="aslink" type="submit" />`
>
> .aslink {
>       background: transparent;
>       border: none;
>       cursor: pointer;
>       text-decoration: underline; }

ideally you would want to write the css out like this:

> input.aslink

doing this will lock down those styles to ONLY being used by input tags with the appropriate class